# autobahn.twisted.websocket IPv6

Tags: python, websocket, server, ipv6

I use autobahn framework to create a websocket server in python.

I use the following code

```
url = "ws://0.0.0.0:" + str(server_port)

ServerFactory = MyServerFactory
factory = ServerFactory(url,
                       debug = True,
                       debugCodePaths = True)
factory.protocol = MyServerFactory
factory.setProtocolOptions(requireMaskedClientFrames = False, applyMask = True)

listenWS(factory)
reactor.run()
```

I need to accept connections not only on IP4 but IPv6 as well.

In the same code I create a HTTP server using the following code:

```
ad = MyWebAdmin()
ad.server = ServerFactory
web = Site(ad)
web.log = lambda _: None # disable annoyingly verbose request logging
reactor.listenTCP(options.webport, web)
```

And it can listen to both IPv4 & IPv6 sockets.

Comment: Try not explicitly listening to an IPv4 address?

Comment: what should I write instead of 
url = "ws://0.0.0.0:"   ?

Comment: try the IPv6 equivalent "ws://[::]"

Comment: It is still not working.
It gives me now WebsocketException: Handshake status 200

very same code works when I use IPv4