# How do you accept IPv6 connections in autobahn.twisted.websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, ipv6, autobahn

I'm running a websocket server using autobahn.twisted.websocket and it works perfectly for IPv4 connections but it doesn't accept IPv6 connections.

The website itself supports IPv6 and is enabled and working but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it working with autobahn.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29970402/4215793) and have implemented the answers but they don't work, as the person that asked that question has said.

How do I configure autobahn to accept IPv6 connections?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    contextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('/path/to/domain.key', '/path/to/domain.cer')
    factory = websocket.WebSocketServerFactory(u"wss://[::1]:9000")
    factory.protocol = ServerProtocol
    websocket.listenWS(factory, contextFactory)

    webdir = static.File(".")
    web = server.Site(webdir)
    reactor.listenSSL(9001, web, contextFactory, 50, "::")
    reactor.run()
```

With this code, websocket connections are able to be opened via IPv4 but it refuses to accept any IPv6 connections. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try to connect to it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Why isn't this just a duplicate of the question you linked to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970402/autobahn-twisted-websocket-ipv6 ?

Comment: And what was the websocket URL you tried to connect to?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone because that doesn't work, as the person that asked that question said and I said.

Comment: @MichaelHampton "wss://domain.tld:9000" - and the AAAA record is correct and working, I can connect to the website through IPv6 via the Nginx server.

Comment: It sure looks like you've bound your websocket listener to localhost. That's not going to work if you want to access it from other computers.

Comment: I can connect via IPv4 just fine, it's just when I specify the IPv6 address it fails to connect. I've tried websocket.WebSocketServerFactory(u"wss://[::]:9000") with no luck as well.

Comment: @Phil Because _what_ doesn't work?  There are no answers on the question you linked to.  There are _comments_ where people ask more questions but no answer is given... That doesn't make this a different question, it just makes it another copy of the same question also with no answer.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Someone in the comments said to change "ws://0.0.0.0:port" to "ws://[::]:port" which is what I tried, and it didn't work. Are duplicate questions not allowed if there's no answer? How will people see the question if its years old unless they have the same problem?

Comment: The site has search functionality.

Comment: I know that, that just means people with the same problem will see it, not someone with an answer. Thank you for pointing out the obvious, though.